# Nuxt - change placement of JavaScripts file when running 'npm run generate'

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, nuxt.js

Is anyone aware of a way to choose where your JavaScript files are placed in the 'dist' folder when running 'npm run generate' in a Nuxt app? By default they go into a '_nuxt' directory, but I need to change this due to my hosting environment.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can use [this](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-builddir/) in the nuxt.config.js

`export default {
  buildDir: 'nuxt-dist'
}`

Comment: this builds all files to 'nuxt-dist' instead of 'dist', but I want to build the js files within 'dist/_nuxt' somewhere else...e.g. 'dist/myjsfiles'...any ideas please?

Comment: this props is a string... you can change it with what you want, in your case
  **buildDir: 'dist'**

Comment: 'buildDir ' changes the build folder name. I need to change the '_nuxt' folder name that sits within that...or ideally place the generated js files outside of that '_nuxt' folder. Therefore this will be a different setting (if at all possible)

Comment: @adamb did you find a way to change the _nuxt dir name?

Comment: @CodeConnoisseur No joy I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

Refer the discussion as mentioned in the comment https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2853#issuecomment-369157568

You may use

```
   // nuxt.config.js
   module.exports = {
      build: {
        publicPath: '/',
      },
   }
```